# Cannot approve transaction on Matcha

Tags: 0x, trading

[image]After I hit approve, this immediately showed up. I tried several times, reset, etc. still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please report this over on https://matcha.xyz/ so that the Matcha support team can help you.